# Why is it much slower to execute in a loop in a plpgsql function than executing independently for each loop without a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a pl-pgsql function to lookup for geo-IP information for multiple addresses. It basically does a loop in the addresses list and looks up one by one. I expect the run time would be similar to the total run time that manually lookup the IP addresses one by one without a function. But it turns out to be much slower. Why?

I tried to test with two IP addresses `27.111.12.93` and `52.23.111.175`. And I also recorded/selected the run time for each loop in the function. On the other hand, I also ran manually for each of the two IP addresses with almost the same SQL and checked the run time with `explain analyze`. I suspected cache affects so I tested multiple times for both, suppose cache factor should affect samely for both sides. 
(BTW, the ipaddress data type is from a Postgres extension ip4r.)

The function code is here:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(ips ipaddress[])
RETURNS TABLE(
    latitude character varying(16),
    longitude character varying(16),
    country_name character varying(60),
    subdivision_1_iso_code character varying(4),
    city_name character varying(100),
    ip ipaddress,
    ts interval
) AS $$
    DECLARE ip ipaddress;
    tstamp timestamptz;
BEGIN
    FOR ip IN SELECT DISTINCT ips_t.ip FROM (SELECT unnest(ips) ip) ips_t
    LOOP
        tstamp := clock_timestamp();
        RETURN QUERY
            SELECT b.latitude, b.longitude, l.country_name, l.subdivision_1_iso_code, l.city_name, ip, clock_timestamp() - tstamp
              FROM blocks4 b
                  INNER JOIN locations l USING (geoname_id)
             WHERE b.network >>= ip
             LIMIT 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE STRICT;
```

And I call it with this:

```sql
select * from test(
ARRAY['27.111.12.93'::ipaddress, '52.23.111.175'::ipaddress]
);
```

Then code for checking each IP address manually is like this:

```
SELECT b.latitude, b.longitude, l.country_name, l.subdivision_1_iso_code, l.city_name, '27.111.12.93'::ipaddress, clock_timestamp()
      FROM blocks4 b
          INNER JOIN locations l USING (geoname_id)
     WHERE b.network >>= '27.111.12.93'::ipaddress
     LIMIT 1;
```

The result of executing the function is:

```
 latitude | longitude | country_name  | subdivision_1_iso_code | city_name |      ip       |       ts
----------+-----------+---------------+------------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------------
 -41.0000 | 174.0000  | New Zealand   |                        |           | 27.111.12.93  | 00:00:00.46761
 39.0481  | -77.4728  | United States | VA                     | Ashburn   | 52.23.111.175 | 00:00:00.485468
(2 rows)
```

As you can see, the execution time for each IP address is more than 400 ms.

Then check them manually one by one, the query time for IP `27.111.12.93` is

```
Planning Time: 0.213 ms
Execution Time: 34.718 ms
```

And for 52.23.111.175:

```
Planning Time: 0.217 ms
Execution Time: 91.154 ms
```

Why the function execution time is much longer given they are basically doing the same thing?

Comment: could you provide `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output for the function call?

Comment: Your statement "as you can see, the execution time for each IP address is more than 400 ms" is not correct. What your data shows is the accumulated to the 1st was 46761ms and the accumulated time for the 2nd was 485468ms, but that includes the time to get the 1st because they're both measured from the same starting time. So getting the 2nd from the 1st required is .485468-.46761= .017858‬ms.

Comment: @Belayer the 2nd doesn't include the time to get the 1st because every loop the `tstamp` is reset to the time of the current loop by this line `tstamp := clock_timestamp();`

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the PL/pgSQL function is executing more queries.

1. SELECT * FROM test(...)
2. SELECT unnest(ips) ip
3. SELECT DISTINCT ips_t.ip FROM #2 above

Followed by running the next query **for each IP** returned by #3. A count of N invocations of #3.

```
SELECT b.latitude, b.longitude, l.country_name, l.subdivision_1_iso_code, l.city_name, ip, clock_timestamp() - tstamp
FROM blocks4 b
  INNER JOIN locations l USING (geoname_id)
WHERE b.network >>= ip
LIMIT 1;
```

So for just two IPs, you are running multiple SQL statements not to mention keeping state for the timestamp and iterating through a nested result set.

If you combined a few instead...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(ips ipaddress[])
RETURNS TABLE(
    latitude character varying(16),
    longitude character varying(16),
    country_name character varying(60),
    subdivision_1_iso_code character varying(4),
    city_name character varying(100),
    ip ipaddress,
    ts interval
) AS $$
  BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (ip)
      b.latitude, b.longitude, l.country_name, l.subdivision_1_iso_code, l.city_name, ip, clock_timestamp()
    FROM unnest(ips) AS ip
      INNER JOIN blocks4 b ON (b.network >>= ip)
      INNER JOIN locations l USING (geoname_id);
    RETURN;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE STRICT;
```

and perhaps throw in an inline window function to track the time differential between runs with [LAG()](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/), I think you'll find your time to process decreased noticeably.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Miles Elam. I actually was using the way you suggested but found it's a bit different from the code I posted. My posted code has a `LIMIT 1` clause which means it stops scanning blocks4/locations as soon as it finds one record for the IP. But this one will scan the entire blocks4/locations tables for all the records meeting the conditions which makes it slower. Also, regarding the extra queries in your comment, as I understand, they are all running outside of the loop (before/after the loop started/finished) so they shouldn't affect the execution time of each loop.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. I've edited my answer to use `DISTINCT ON (ip)`. This will perform the logical equivalent of your LIMIT statement.

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/

Comment: Actually I tried the `DISTINCT ON(ip)` too. It seems still scans for the full table and just does an `unique()` action at the last (from what I can see in the explain analyze). In terms of the run time, I didn't see much improvement.